# gcd of polynomials over Z_7

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

I want the gcd of the two polynomials:

$$f=x^5+3x^4+5x^3+x^2+x+3$$

$$g=2x^3+4x^2+x$$

in $Z_7[x]$.

My approach:

I use the euclidean algorithm and continue until I get no remainder.

$$(x^5+3x^4+5x^3+x^2+x+3):(2x^3+4x^2+x) = (4x^2+4x+3) + (6x^2+5x+3)$$

Step 2:

$$(2x^3+4x^2+x):(6x^2+5x+3) = (5x)+(0)$$

Is that correct? So the gcd of $f$ and $g$ is $5x$?! Or do I have to do more?

Comment: There is a mistake somewhere in the computation, since $5x$ does not divide $f$.  But the general idea is correct.

Comment: @hardmath I think computation are correct. The fact is that when you get remainder $=0$, the GCD is the previous remainder. So the GCD should be $6x^2+5x+3$.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing as @Crostul, but in more words. Your error, if any, was to pay too much attention to the quotients. It’s just the remainders that count, here.

Comment: Consider that $g(x)=2x(x-1)(x-4)$. To find the gcd, you only need to compute $f(0),f(1),f(4)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating the/a GCD for polynomials over a field is virtually the same as calculating the GCD in the integers.

Define a sequence of successive  *remainders* $r_k$ like so:

- Set $r_0 =f$.
- Set $r_1 = g$.
- As long as $r_k\neq 0$ set $r_{k+1}$ the remainder of the division of $r_{k-1}$ by $r_k$.

This will generate a finite sequence of remainders $r_0, r_1 , \dots r_n, r_{n+1} = 0$.

*A* GCD of $f$ and $g$ is given by $r_n$ the last non-zero remainder.
That is in your case $6x^2 + 5x + 3$.

However, note this is *a* GCD, not really the GCD, as multiplication by any non-zero element of the base field would yield another GCD.

Furthermore, sometimes the convention is in place that *the* GCD is the normed polynomial that is a GCD. If you are working under this assumption you should multiply $6x^2 + 5x + 3$ by  an appropriate constant to get the normed polynomial associated to that one. (This is analogous the convention that  the GCD of two integers is positive.)

Comment: Just to illustrate Quid's point, the monic polynomial "associated" to $6x^2 + 5x + 3$ is $x^2 + 2x + 4$, meaning that the latter is a unit multiple of the former.