# Find GCD of polynomials over GF(101)

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, cryptography

Hello all I'm teaching myself cryptography, and I'm struggling with polynomial arithmetic over finite fields. I've some what been able to teach myself how to do the arithmetic over $GF(2)$, but when the finite field increase to higher numbers like $GF(101)$ I struggle with long division aspect as it relates to the 101. The specific question I'm struggling with is to determine the GCD of the polynomials: $x^5 + 88x^4 + 73x^3 + 83x^2 + 51x + 67$ and $x^3 + 97x^2 + 40x + 38$ over $GF(101)$.

I'm a little new on this site so I still need to learn how to structure questions. Any help would be great

Comment: Do you know how to add, subtract, multiply and divide in $GF(101)$? If you know that, proceed like you would in the reals. There really is no algorithmic difference.

Comment: Take a look at for example [this older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1027559/11619). Does that help? May be not, if you have trouble with long division? Long division of polynomials goes the same way over any field. The only difference is that you cannot do division by constants the same way you would do it over $\Bbb{Q}$. So may be you should first review modular division before delving into long division of modular polynomials? Anyway, +1 for explaining where your difficulties are!